# need help install geoDjango on windows

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, geodjango

i have no idea how to install GeoDjango i just follow tutorials from here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/install/#windows)

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis import gdal
>>> gdal.HAS_GDAL
False
```

> PATH - C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\gdal

i have done some installation:

- python2.7 already installed (with sqlite) path c:\python27
- PostgreSQL 9.4
- PostGIS (after click finish i got some popsup)

[image]

[image]

- psycopg2
- OSGeo4W

**Modify Windows environment:**

> Success

- set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
- set PYTHON_ROOT=C:\Python27
- set GDAL_DATA=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\gdal
- set PROJ_LIB=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\proj
- set PATH=%PATH%;%PYTHON_ROOT%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin

> Unsuccessful ( Error: Access is denied )

- reg ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
  Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d "%PATH%"
- reg ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
  Manager\Environment" /v GDAL_DATA /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d
  "%GDAL_DATA%"
- reg ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
  Manager\Environment" /v PROJ_LIB /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d "%PROJ_LIB%"

***I really need GeoDjango installed Please everybody take a look and i will be grateful for your help.
thanks in advance***

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, save for the suggestion that you run this stuff in a VM like Virtualbox if you can.  Windows is generally unfriendly to stuff like this, and you'll find that your life will be considerably easier if you just run everything in Linux (in VM).

Comment: I tried installing `OsGeo` in Windows. Never worked. I switched to Linux. Although I'd like to see a solution for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on command prompt and open as administrator. It will work

Answer (score 0):

For the **first problem** (**HAS_GDAL = False**), Python is not detecting GDAL installation because of Windows Environmental Variables are not set correctly.

I only could solve this problem giving up [OSGeo4w](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) and using [GDAL and MapServer](http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1800-x64-gdal-1-11-4-mapserver-6-4-3.zip).

For the **second problem** (Error: Access is denied), you cannot add/edit registry because you are not using administrator. As *Awe Oluwatobi* said, click on **Windows Key**, write **Command**, right click on **Command Prompt** and select **Run as Administrator**. After this, run the same commands.

Comment: `HAS_GDAL` doesn't seem to work for me, but ` gdal.GDAL_VERSION` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

download gdal.exe file (for python 2) then add path in your setting.py

e.g
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH='C:/Program Files (x86)/GDAL/gdal201.dll'

geodjango is django only that has geospatial database.

## install django

pip install django==2.2.7

Answer (score 0):

I got through all the set commands, but this command fails.....reg ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d "%PATH%"